# PHP- boolean in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I have field value **$copyContent** which, when dumping returns:

```
"true"
```

It's actually *boolean* filed which I am pulling out trough request from endpoint like:

```
'/api/copy/6?copy_content=true'
```

I want to check that if it's true or it's false. I tried:

```
 if ($copyContent === "TRUE") {
     echo 'Do it!'
 } else {
     echo 'Do not do it!'
 }
```

and also just:

```
 if ($copyContent)
```

or:

```
 if ($copyContent === true)
```

Non of this examples work as it should. Can you tell what am I doing wrong?

Update:

I tried with:

```
 if (filter_var($copyContent, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {}
```

This works.. Can this be suitable solution?

Comment: When you had `$copyContent === "TRUE"`, but you say its value is `"true"`, the case is expected to match.

Comment: please note that "true" is not boolean, it's a string. a string will always be equal to true, as far as i know.

Comment: How do you initialize the `$copyContent` variable? `if ($copyContent)` would have given `true` for a string `"true"` (any non-empty string is true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value that you are getting is lowercase "true" and you are comparing it with uppercase, it won't match.

```
 if ($copyContent === "TRUE") {
```

You can either do

```
if (strtoupper($copyContent) === "TRUE") {
```

OR your last option should be just fine.

```
if (filter_var($copyContent, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using === will check if the variable and its type is the same.
I assume that your $copyContent is a string set to be equal as "true".
$copyContent === "TRUE", will check if both values the same and if both are strings.
As you probably know, 'true' is not the same as 'TRUE', so, it will print, 'Do not do it!'.
This docs might help you https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php